# Verificar se pagina foi carregada após botao ser clicado

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho um botão que chama outros 4 botões via jquery, cada botão abre uma nova aba e fica em estado de load até que o pdf seja baixado automaticamente, preciso verificar se essa pagina terminou de carregar para chamar os outros botões. Alguma sugestão?

```
function gerarTodosRelatorios(){    

 jQuery('.button1').on('click', function (e) {
     e.preventDefault();

     var target = jQuery(".button2");
     var target2 = jQuery(".button3");
     var target3 = jQuery(".button4");
     var target4 = jQuery(".button5");


     target[0].click();
     target2[0].click();
     target3[0].click();
     target4[0].click();
 });}
```

Answer (score 1):

Não sei exatamente como você está abrindo as abas, mas creio que você precise manter a referência da aba aberta e chamar a outra aba no onload dela.

Por exemplo:

```
var aba= window.open('http://stackoverflow.com/', '_blank');
if (aba) {
    //navegador permitiu a abertura
    aba.onload(function(){
    //chamar aba 2

    });
} else {
    //Navegador bloqueou !
    alert('Bloqueado pelo bloqueador de popup');
}
```

isso considerando que a aba que você diz seja uma aba do navegador, se for uma aba do HTML como um bootstrap da vida, basta usar o `onload` nela

Comment: a aba esta sendo aberta após clicar em um link, esse link abre uma função em java que gera um relatorio.
 <a href="abrirNotificacaoPostagem.action?
acao=imprimir"  class="spwBotao button3"  target="_blank">Lote CRM</a>

Comment: Você só vai conseguir "enxergar" uma aba do navegador que você tenha a referência no momento da criação, então creio que você tenha que alterar onde a aba é aberta.